# Allure report with build number Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, allure

I am created Web App in Azure Portal. And set up Allure report plugin to Azure Devops. Everything work fine, but when I start new pipeline with test, the old test information in the portal is removed and the new one is added. It turns out that in the end I can not view the old information about the tests when I want. I tried to configure the Allure report step so that the folder that will be created has its own $(Build.BuildNumber), but if it is uploaded via FTP to the portal, the portal becomes inaccessible because a folder with a report appears in the path /site/wwwroot and the portal does not reproduce it.
How do I need to set up my web app or steps in azure devops so that I can save and view reports, both old and new?

Answer (score 0):

The Allure Generate Build Step will only generate the Allure report and save it as a build artifact. Then, using [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) to copy the repots to Microsoft Azure storage blobs may help you to collect all the reports. Then, you could access the blob with all the reports as you want.

Comment: How do I set up the configuration so that after a pipeline run I can view the report in Azure Devops?

Comment: How do we install the allure in Azure dev ops pipeline